# Why doesn't this code to change text on Android work?

Tags: java, android, textview

This code to change text when the user presses a button doesn't work. Why?

```
package com.cookbook.simple_activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class activity extends Activity {
    private TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_text);
    Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trigger);
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple);


   startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            txt.setText(R.string.pressthisbutton);
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: See the edit to my answer. There's nothing to change it to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

```
    public class activity extends Activity {
    private TextView txt;
    Button startButton;
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_text);
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trigger);
```

You need to initialize your `Views` after inflating your `layout` with `setContentView()`. Since your `Views` exist in your `layout`, they will return `null` if you haven't inflated your `layout` first. You can declare them before your `setContentView()` but you can't initialize them until after.

Also, since you are trying to access `txt` inside your `listener` it must either be `final` or declared as a member variable as above.

This was a rather easy one to spot but they aren't always. When you post a question try to describe what isn't working and how. Here it would be a `NPE` I'm guessing when you try to set the `listener` on your `Button` so it crashes. When it does crash, please provide the logcat so it is easier for us to spot the problem.

**Edit**

After seeing your xml, you are using the same `string` value for your initial text as you are for the text when you click the `Button` so of course it doesn't change. I'm not sure what you're after here but the code is running as it should as it is written.

Comment: Tried it still it doesn't change the text when the button is pressed.

Comment: Are you getting any error or just nothing is happening? Are you sure that `pressthisbutton` is a value defined in `strings.xml`?

Comment: if i put a toast inside the listener then some functions show syntax error

Comment: ok if i want to change the text to say google i gave txt.SetText("google"); but still nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

try this code ....

you need to declare the

```
 TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_text); 

 Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trigger);
```

after the create method otherwise it doesnot recognize id android Activity lifecycle starts with the

`onCreate()` method

```
package com.cookbook.simple_activity;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class activity extends Activity {
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple);

        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_text);
        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trigger);

       startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                txt.setText(R.string.pressthisbutton);
            }
        });
     }
    }
```

Comment: Close but this will create a compile error inside the `listener`

Comment: It says **Illegal modifier for parameter txt; Only final is permitted** now what do i do??

Comment: plz dont use private modifer for the TextView

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your layout is **android_simple**

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple);
```

but you are setting contentView as **activity_simple**

**EDIT: 1** Do this

Initiallization of you textView and button in onCreate because this   `setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple);`
says where to find the view but you set the view before telling the layout file

```
TextView txt = null;
Button startButton = null;

 @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_text);
    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trigger);

   startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            txt.setText(R.string.pressthisbutton);
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: Tried it still it doesn't change the text when the button is pressed.

Comment: @Audi why don't you paste you xml

Comment: strings.xml-----> http://pastebin.com/4LzKiTxb
androidmanifest.xml----->http://pastebin.com/n5PxWqGR

Comment: please help I have uploaded the XML files as per your request but still you haven't responded to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
txt.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.pressthisbutton));
```

Comment: its in kitkat android's post comments check it